# how to NOT save a bean property value into mongodb using spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am having a simple bean with getters and setters and some properties and I want to not save the property value into MongoDB using spring-data-mongodb

Example Request Body:

```
{"accountId":"XXXXXXXXXX", // This should be saved
    "creditCardNo":"XXXXXX" //This should NOT Be saved
}
```

The class Person :

```
  class Person
  {
   public Person(){}
   public Person(String a , String b)
   {
    this.accountId = a;
    this.creditCardNo = b; //This should not be saved
    }
      private String accountId;
      @Transient //Spring-data transient
      private transient String creditCardNo; //This should not be saved into db
      /* Getter and Setter methods go here */
     }
       /* After some validations */
     Person p = new Person("xxx","yyy");
       mongoTemplate.save(p); //Saves xxx and yyy BUT xxx must have been saved and yyy is transient should NOT BE SAVED.
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing when u use Transient

Comment: the transient items are  saved in mongodb, BUT it should not be saved in my case, however its NOT a good practice its  to initialize to nulls that need not be saved , please help

Comment: try this `@Transient
      private String creditCardNo` No need to use transient type before String